# Transforming Variables in time series regression

Tags: time-series, regression

I have multiple quarterly time series data and trying to build a linear regression model using this dataset.

1. Should the transformations on the LHS and RHS be the same i.e QoQ percent changes?
2. Could we have Qi/Qi-4 percentage changes on the independent variables to predict QoQ (Qi/Qi-1) changes in response variable?
3. If yes, is there any literature or book that illustrates or refutes this fact.

Comment: Why "linear regression" for time-series? Did you consider ARIMA?

Comment: Try reading [this St. Louis FED publication](https://research.stlouisfed.org/publications/review/10/11/Armesto.pdf)

Comment: Yes. I have tried ARIMAX (1,0,0), gives you similar results as OLS. 

I have read this pub., it talks about modeling lhs and RHS which are at different frequencies and coverting to one or the other , in my case the frequency of the dataset is the same quarterly. I am trying to find out if quarterly changes can be explained by yearly changes and whether the necessary residuals test will hold.